# Something keeps throwing output in a new line

Tags: bash, shell

```
for f in *.*
do
echo -n | ls $f | rev | sed 's/^[^.]*//g'| sed 's/^.//' | rev
echo -n " ima koncnico "
echo -n | ls $f | rev | cut -d . -f1 | rev
done
```

I have the following code which should all be echoed in the same line for each iteration of the for loop. What my output looks like:

```
examples
 ima koncnico desktop
naloga_2
 ima koncnico sh
naloga_6
 ima koncnico sh
NALOGE
 ima koncnico zip
UVOS.tar
 ima koncnico xz
```

What it should look like:

```
examples ima koncnico desktop
naloga_2 ima koncnico sh
naloga_6 ima koncnico sh
NALOGE ima koncnico zip
UVOS.tar ima koncnico xz
```

Why is this happening? I'm assuming it has something to do with ls. What's the best solution?

Comment: `echo -n` doesn't output anything by itself, which is somewhat irrelevant because `ls` doesn't read its standard input anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About your problem at hand:**

`echo -n | something` won't do anything useful in most cases. It outputs nothing and pipes that nothing into something else.

Your solution is `echo -n $(something)`, because that runs `something` and then outputs that output *without the trailing newline*.

```sh
for f in *.*
do
  echo -n $(ls $f | rev | sed 's/^[^.]*//g'| sed 's/^.//' | rev)
  echo -n " ima koncnico "
  ls $f | rev | cut -d . -f1 | rev
done
```

I removed the last `echo` entirely since you need a newline there anyway, otherwise *all* files are is one line.

A way to write this in a perhaps clearer manner would be this:

```sh
for f in *.*
do
  NAME=$(ls $f | rev | sed 's/^[^.]*//g'| sed 's/^.//' | rev)
  EXT=$(ls $f | rev | cut -d . -f1 | rev)
  echo "$NAME ima koncnico $EXT"
done
```

---

**About a better method in general:**

The whole pipeline is actually not necessary - there are simpler ways. As mentioned by user oguz ismail in their answer, [you can use parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60593187/1871033).

Answer (score 4):

Just use parameter expansions; you don't need that pipeline, and it doesn't do what you think it does anyways.

```
for f in *.*; do
    printf '%s ima koncnico %s\n' "${f%.*}" "${f##*.}"
done
```